# Collapse navbar stay opened after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I need to help with **CLOSING** the nav-bar in the mobile version of the site. When I select the item in nav bar: it stays open, it doesn't close automatically, so i need to click again on the menu to close

https://jsfiddle.net/jrr3u08c/

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="mobile-box">
        <a class="mobile" href="#">MENU</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-menu">
        <div class="sidebar1 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xs-12" ng-if="authentication.isAuth" ng-cloak>
            <ul id="nav" ng-cloak>
                <li ng-if="IsUser()"><a ui-sref="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li ng-if="IsAdmin()"><a ui-sref="item">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.mobile").click(function() {
        $(".sidebar1").slideToggle('fast');
    });
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        if($(window).width() >880) {
            $(".sidebar1").show();
        }
        else {
            $(".sidebar1").hide();
        }
    }; 
});
```

**EDIT**: Added Angular-js tag to question.

Comment: Quick stab: What if you made a function that just calls 

    `$(".sidebar1").slideToggle('fast');`

Then called that function in each menu item's ng-click

Comment: sry, my English is not good, can you help me with example...

Comment: Is it bootstrap navbar?

Comment: no, it is not bootstrap menu.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are not using bootstrap navigation bars?

you can refer http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h for reference.

Comment: I try with bootstrap nav, but I already make full angular js dashboard, without bootstrap. And last week I try with bootstrap nav, but I have problem with implementing vertical menu with bootstrap in my app.

Answer (score 1):

You can even use `hover()` instead of `click()`.It works like a charm.

```
$("a.mobile").hover(function() {
    $(".sidebar1").slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: thnx man, interesting solution. I keep it in mind  if no one give me solution with click(). Thnx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need like this. Try this [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jrr3u08c/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.mobile, .menu-item").click(function() {
    $(".sidebar1").slideToggle('fast');
  });
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    if ($(window).width() > 880) {
      $(".sidebar1").show();
    } else {
      $(".sidebar1").hide();
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mobile-box">
  <a class="mobile" href="#">MENU</a>
</div>
<div class="menu-menu">
  <div class="sidebar1 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xs-12" ng- if="authentication.isAuth" ng-cloak>
    <ul id="nav" ng-cloak>
      <li ng-if="IsUser()"><a class="menu-item" ui-sref="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-if="IsAdmin()"><a class="menu-item" ui-sref="item">Item</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```